# how to perform an if function when a button is pressed (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

**HTML**

```
<button id="submit" onClick="">Finish questionnaire</button><br/>
```

**Javascript**

```
var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');
var x = 0;

$(":radio").change(function() {

    x = x + 1

    if (x == 3) {
        alert("Submitted")
    } else {
        alert("not submitted")
    }

});
```

I am making a short questionnaire website. I would like to have submit button at the bottom of my page which will run the javascript code. This code will either give an alert of submit or not submitted. If the user has answered all the questions, then the alert will say submitted, otherwise, if a question is missed out, it will say not submitted. I have my javascript code, but I dont know how to implement it with a button. Please help

Comment: You could literally find the answer to this question with one google search

Comment: `onClick="window.location = 'https://goo.gl/IgTR87'"`

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#submit").click( function() {
   // whatever you want
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it in a `.click(function(){CODE HERE})`

Answer (score 0):

You need eventListener for button click. A very simple Google search can give you the answer fast enough.
Still for your convenience, I'm writing the answer here for button click.

```
var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');
var x = 0;

submitButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

    x = x + 1

    if (x == 3) {
        alert("Submitted")
    } else {
        alert("not submitted")
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```js
var x = 0;

$('#submit').click(function() {

    x = x + 1

    if (x == 3) {
        alert("Submitted")
    } else {
        alert("not submitted")
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="submit">Finish questionnaire</button><br/>
```